# Command rm not working on Mac OS I get permission denied

Tags: macos, filesystems, sudo, rm, ccache

I am using ccache and it is stuck in a state that blocks all builds that use it. I tried doing `ccache --clear` but the command simply hangs, so I went ahead and decided to delete the `.ccache` folder manually but I am getting permission denied.

stat output for one of the files:

```
16777221 8590811525 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user7 staff 0 0 "Feb  2 12:29:36 2018" "Feb  2 12:29:36 2018" "Feb  2 18:51:03 2018" "Feb  2 12:29:36 2018" 4194304 0 0
```

then I tried:

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg ./*

sudo chflags -R noschg ./*
```

then I tried disabling system integrity, still no luck. When I do

```
sudo rm -fR ./*
```

I get permission denied

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same issue on Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu